# overflow and height in safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Good day, everyone. I try to create a website with popups that have overflow CSS property. I try to do it by using grid and flex but it can't help me. (In chrome that works perfectly) [image: enter image description here. I will attach a photo with HTML and CSS properties.]

[image]

Comment: Hello :) Can you add code snippet so that we could help you

Comment: probably a duplicate, lots of results for the 100% height issue in safari: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=100%25+height+safari